# How do nested jobs lunched in the viewModelScope work?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am new to the Koltin coroutine and sometimes it gets confusing. Let's suppose that in my View Model I am collecting a flow as follows:

```
viewModelScope.launch A@{
    uiState.collect { state ->
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The block *A* is supposed to collect the states as long as viewModelScope is available. Now, what if I want to launch another job inside the **collect** block?

I think if I do it like this

```
var jobBAlreadyLaunched = false
viewModelScope.launch A@{
    uiState.collect { state ->
        if (state.isOk && !jobBAlreadyLaunched) {
             launch B@{
                 anotherState.collect { res->
                     jobBAlreadyLaunched = true
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the block *B* will get cancelled if the job *A* cancels. So I changes my code to this:

```
var jobCAlreadyLaunched = false
viewModelScope.launch A@{
    uiState.collect { state ->
        if (state.isOk && !jobCAlreadyLaunched) {
             viewModelScope.launch C@{
                 anotherState.collect { res->
                     jobCAlreadyLaunched = true
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I think the block *C* is bound to the *viewModelScope* and is independent from the block *A*'s coroutine scope so the coroutine *C* will continue working as long as *viewModelScope* is active. **Is that concept generally correct?**

I want to launch the coroutine *C* once state.isOk is true and let it collect the *res* updates until the view model is active but I am not sure whether this implementation is correct.

I think if the block *C* gets suspended it won't suspend the block *A*. Is that correct?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the different behaviors between B and C is correct.

B is a child coroutine of A, so it will be canceled when A is cancelled. Also, the job A will not be complete until B is complete.

C is a sibling coroutine of B and will run completely independently. Since `viewModelScope` is constructed using a SupervisorJob, A and C can fail independently from each other.

> I think if the block C gets suspended it won't suspend the block A. Is that correct?

Correct. This is also essentially true for B, except that when A gets to the end of its `launch` lambda, it will still be waiting for the launched B to complete before it is considered complete.